# How do I combine changeset errors?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to combine changeset errors.

I have a Institution schema which belongs to a User schema. Some fields are required on each but the error response looks like:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "user": {
            "password_confirmation": [
                "The password confirmation does not match the password."
            ],
            "password": [
                "This field is required."
            ],
            "name": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        },
        "institution": {
            "web_address": [
                "is required."
            ]
        },

    }
}
```

How do I combine these error objects into one?

My insert looks like:

```
 user_changeset =
      User.normal_user_changeset(%User{}, %{
        :email => Map.get(attrs, "email"),
        :password => Map.get(attrs, "password"),
        :password_confirmation => Map.get(attrs, "password_confirmation"),
        :name => Map.get(attrs, "name"),
        :postcode => Map.get(attrs, "postcode"),
        :dob => Map.get(attrs, "dob")
      })

    institution =
      %Institution{}
      |> Institution.changeset(%{
        :web_address => Map.get(attrs, "web_address"),
        :person_responsible => Map.get(attrs, "person_responsible"),
        :annual_turnover => Map.get(attrs, "annual_turnover")
      })
      |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:user, user_changeset)
      |> Repo.insert()
```

I'd like the error response to be:

```
 {
        "errors": {
                "password_confirmation": [
                    "The password confirmation does not match the password."
                ],
                "password": [
                    "This field is required."
                ],
                "name": [
                    "This field is required."
                ]
                "web_address": [
                    "is required."
                ]
        }
    }
```

I have this function in my fallback controller (here by default):

```
  def call(conn, {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset}) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    |> render(SfiWeb.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
  end
```

Comment: Please clarify what do you want to get (the outcome example would be nice.)

Comment: What do you mean by "combine" here? What's the output you want for the error output you've shown?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: FYI: You don't need to manually get the values for string keys in the `attrs` map. You can pass it to cast directly and `Ecto` will handle it for you: `User.normal_user_changeset(%User{}, attrs)`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the values of the `errors` field and merge them all using `Enum.reduce/3`:

```
map = Jason.decode! """
{
    "errors": {
        "user": {
            "password_confirmation": [
                "The password confirmation does not match the password."
            ],
            "password": [
                "This field is required."
            ],
            "name": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        },
        "institution": {
            "web_address": [
                "is required."
            ]
        }
    }
}
"""

Map.update!(map, "errors", fn errors ->
  errors |> Map.values() |> Enum.reduce(%{}, &Map.merge/2)
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
%{
  "errors" => %{
    "name" => ["This field is required."],
    "password" => ["This field is required."],
    "password_confirmation" => ["The password confirmation does not match the password."],
    "web_address" => ["is required."]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`errors` is just one of the values in `%Ecto.Changeset{}` struct.

That said, one always might modify `%Ecto.Changeset{}` to provide custom `errors`:

```rb
def fix_errors(%Ecto.Changeset{errors: errors} = ch) do
  %Ecto.Changeset{ch | errors: errors ++ [:my_custom_error]}
end
```

What you need is just to remap your input using the function like the one above and embed the result into your changeset chain:

```rb
institution =
  %Institution{}
  |> ...
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:user, user_changeset)
  |> fix_errors() # see above 
  |> Repo.insert()
```

---

Whether you have provided the valid Elixir terms for `errors` before and after, I could show how to perform the transformation itself. E.g.:

```rb
errors = %{
  institution: %{web_address: ["is required"]},
  user: %{
    name: ["is required."],
    password: ["is required."],
    password_confirmation: ["no match"]
  }
}
```

Might be flattened as:

```rb
input
|> Enum.map(fn {_, v} -> v end)
|> Enum.reduce(&Map.merge/2)
#⇒ %{
#   name: ["is required."],
#   password: ["is required."],
#   password_confirmation: ["no match"],
#   web_address: ["is required"]
# }
```